# How to make a Texture2D 50% transparent? XNA

Tags: xna, transparency, opacity

I'm using SpriteBatch to draw a Texture2D on the screen and was wondering how I could manipulate the the images opacity? Anyone know the best way in accomplishing this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Assuming you are using XNA 4.0 with premultiplied alpha. In your spritebatch.draw multiply the color by a float, 0.5f for 50% transparency, and draw as you would normally. If you are not using premultiplied alpha I suggest you do for performance reasons and its more intuitive after you get used to it.

Example:

```
_spriteBatch.Draw(texture, location, Color.White * 0.5f);
```

Edit:
Also make sure you set your blend state to BlendState.AlphaBlend, or another blend state that supports alpha and is not NonPremultiplied.

Example:

```
_spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
```

Comment: Using the multiplication operator on `Color` modulates all four channels (RGBA) and only provides the expected change in transparency when using premultiplied blending modes (eg: `AlphaBlend`) . For other blend states to work as expected (eg: `Additive` and `NonPremultiplied`) you should set the alpha value of the colour directly (leaving RGB alone).

Answer (score 6):

Just use color as `new Color(RGBA);` where:

- R is Red
- G is Green
- B is Blue
- A is Alpha

For instance:

```
new Color(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

Comment: This may not have been intentional but you just showed me that the `Color` parameter is not en enum lol! I had no idea you could create your own colors like that.